# How to resize an OpenGL widget inside a Qt form class

Tags: qt, opengl, resize, widget, qglwidget

I have an OpenGL widget (`myWidget`) inside a `QVBoxLayout` (`verticalLayout_2`), in a Qt form class (`MyForm`).

I want to resize the OpenGL widget when the form has been resized.

What should I write inside the changeEvent method, to resize the `QVBoxLayout` and the OpenGL widget to the new size?

```
MyForm::MyForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myWidget = new GL_Widget;
    ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget( myWidget );
    adjustSize();
}

void MyForm::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    // What should I write here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to write any code to automatically resize your child widget. (Also, `changeEvent()` is not the correct event handler for this purpose anyway.)

Your problem is likely with the layout that you've created with Qt Designer. You probably dragged a vertical layout from the sidebar into your form widget, which is actually doesn't create a top-level layout. It's very easy to make this mistake.

Instead, do one of the following to create top-level layouts in Qt Designer:

- Right-click on your top-level (form) widget in the Object Inspector, and choose one of the layouts from the "Lay Out" menu.
- Select your top-level widget and click on one of the layout icons in the toolbar:

  [image: qt designe r toolbar]

If you set up your layout(s) correctly, you don't need to add any code. Your layout will update automatically if you preview your form in Qt Designer.

Comment: Thank you @jmk , I solved the issue by choosing "Lay out -> Lay Out in a Grid" after right click in the form, from Qt Designer. Now the form is automatically resized without using the changeEvent method.